# Forward a website request to an internal ip

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, routing

I've written a web app for use at work that I will be running on a local server.

Everyone on the local network will be able to access it. I can currently access it with a local IP (ex. *192.168.1.65*).

Which is great for tech-savvy people, but I'd like for the employees to be able to type in something like **www.quickapp.com** and have our router automatically reroute the request to the local IP instead of to the outside.

Is this possible, and if so, how can it be done?

Comment: If they are on the same LAN, then why not just use the computer's hostname?  Otherwise, setup a local DNS server.

Comment: This would be a great solution except that typing in the host name only brings me to a google search, or in the case of a ping, a 'could not find host'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve an internal DNS record.

1. You have to define an A-record on your DNS server. If you are running a Microsoft Windows server, this is quite simple to achieve. 
   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/adding-host-a-dns-records-in-windows-server-2008-r2
   . If you are using the default DNS service of your router, it will differ on the model if it works.
2. Adding a record to your Windows hosts file. You have to change this file to all computers which want to use your adress. 
   What this file does is nothing else then translating an DNS name you type to an IP adres. This overrules the local and external DNS servers which could have records of the given name. You could even change Google.com to your webserver.
   http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: Solution 1 sounds better for me. I don't currently have access to the router, but will soon. Thanks for the answer :)